# one to many relationship in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have a table that has the following columns

Item Table:
Id, Tags, AnotherColumn

and a second table:
Tags Table:
Id, TagName, Description

I would like the item tables tags column to be a collection of values from the tags table TagName column but i dont know how to model this in sql server.  Does anyone know how to be model this so that if i remove a record from the tags table it will remove that tag reference from the item table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want your item table like that.

You want an additional `ItemTags` table, with:

`ID, ItemID, TagID`

This will allow you to map multiples and still enforce constraints.  It sounds like you want a "list" in the `Tags` field which is a terrible idea.

Comment: Agreed.  Multi-value columns are counter to 1NF, and _extremely_ difficult to deal with.